# Changing a connection password in Waton Studio Desktop V1.1

Tags: data-science-experience, watson-studio, watson-studio-desktop

I need to change a DB2 for Z/OS connection password in my local windows Watson Studio Desktop (v1.1) 
But it seems in Edit Connections, password field is greyed out and red circle bar displays when hovered over.   What's the process to change the password?  It's not in the documentation

Answer (score 1):

The edit connection currently only allows modifying the connection name or description.  This is tracked as an issue and will be addressed in the future.  In order to 'change' the password you will need to delete and recreate the connection.

Comment: And for completeness, any data refinery flow or modeling flow using these connections, would also have to be redone.